# Wrapping a capturing lambda as a function pointer in a template function

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which converts a capturing lambda to non-capturing lambda so it can be passed as a function pointer to a C-style API:

(`Statistics` here is a simple struct)

```
auto closure = [&](Statistics stats) {
    setStats(stats);
};

auto wrapper = +[](Statistics stats, void* userdata) {
    (*static_cast<decltype(closure)*>(userdata))(stats);
};

call_callback (wrapper, &closure);
```

Since this pattern will be used a few times in my application, I wanted to generalise it into a templated function:

```
template <typename T>
auto wrap_closure(std::function<void(T)> closure) -> void(*)(T, void*)
{
    auto wrapper = +[](T data, void* userdata) {
        (*static_cast<decltype(closure)*>(userdata))(data);
    };
    return wrapper;
}
```

However if I try to use it I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in `std::function`:

```
auto closure = [&](Statistics stats) {
    setStats(stats);
};

call_callback (wrap_closure<Statistics> (closure), &closure);
```

Should I not be using `std::function` here?

Comment: @MaxLanghof that's not a problem since it's only used to provide its type. The actual issue is that `&closure` is an erased pointer to the original lambda, while `wrap_closure` is setup to cast it into an `std::function`.

Comment: @Quentin Right, my bad.

Comment: @Quentin storing the closure as a `std::function` member fixes the issue. Is there a way to achieve the same result without storing the closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `decltype(closure)` inside `wrap_closure` is `std::function<void(Statistics)>`, while the original `closure` whose address you pass in is a lambda. They are not the same type, thus the `static_cast` through `void *` has undefined behaviour.

You can fix it either way, either keep the `std::function` but ensure that both sides agree:

```
std::function<void(Statistics)> f = closure;
call_callback (wrap_closure(f), &f);
```

... which is quite brittle as you've noticed, or get rid of `std::function` and use the type of `closure` as-is:

```
template <typename... T, typename Callable>
auto wrap_closure(Callable const &) -> void(*)(T..., void*)
{
    return +[](T... data, void* userdata) {
        (*static_cast<Callable*>(userdata))(data...);
    };
}

// Usage
call_callback (wrap_closure<Statistics>(closure), &closure);
```

Variadic salt and pepper free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda are not `std::function`. As you arleady call `wrap_closure<Statistics> (closure)`, you might use instead:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto wrap_closure(F& closure) -> void(*)(T, void*)
{
    return +[](T data, void* userdata) {
        (*static_cast<F*>(userdata))(data);
    };
}
```

You can go further by using function traits to know argument of the functor to not have to provide `T`.